# Installing PHP PECL module on OpenShift

Tags: php, openshift

I'm trying to install the PECL oauth module on OpenShift by declaring the following in the file `.openshift/pear.txt`

```
pecl/oauth
```

I believe that this is the preferred way to declare project dependencies for PHP projects on OpenShift but I get the following build error;

```
failed to write /opt/rh/php54/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/oauth.so
(copy(/opt/rh/php54/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/oauth.so): 
failed to open stream: Permission denied)
```

Is it possible to include this module or must I create a custom cartridge?

Thanks

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing. Any luck with this?

Comment: No, sorry. I believe that it is not possible to simply declare the oauth module as a dependency as it is not a _userland_ module. I think _userland_ has special meaning in php but I'm not familiar with it. I concluded that I must create a custom cartridge or wait for Openshift to include oauth in their quickstart cartridge. I'm still waiting!

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that module is already installed?  Have you tried creating a phpinfo(); page to see what modules are already installed and available?

Comment: Sadly not. A third party 'plugin' is complaining that it needs the module and there is **no** mention of it in the output of phpinfo.